# Meaning of $\rho_b$ in equation for air density

Tags: definition, notation, atmospheric-science, density

I looked for an equation for air density in different parts of the atmosphere and found the [barometric formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula#Density_equations) on wikipedia. My only problem is that I don't understand what p_b means in the formula. The red circle shows what I mean exactly.

[image: Barometric formula]

Comment: The Wikipedia article seems to explain this just below that equation, starting at *"The value of subscript b ranges [...]"*. Can you be more specific what you think is lacking about Wikipedia's explanation?

Comment: The "b"  taking integer values 1 to 6  relates to the atmospheric layer and the values of $p_b$ etc  are given in the table in the article you cite.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking if I have to put the integer values from 1 to 6 and calculate with that. So: p = 1[....]

Answer (score -2):

It is the density at the (b)ottom of the atmosphere.